# Calculating probability with multiple conditions

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, standard-deviation, quantiles

I am trying to understand something. Let's say we have 2000 samples and two different conitions. If we use condition #1, we get a result but if we use condition #2, we get different result. Is there a correct way of solving or working on such problem?

Example:
I log my daily driving routine (distance and speed). Let's say i drive 25km today and my average speed is 75km/h. If i try to get the percentile to predict tomorrow's distance using past distances, i get a result but if i calculate using the speed, i also get a probability but it's different. But both works in long tests. I'm trying to findout if there's a better way to calculate probability using multiple conditions or maybe calculate a different percentile score using two different conditions.

EDIT:
I am getting percentile's for the next day. So sometimes 50th percentile is 65km if i use condition #1 but for the same day i get 55km if i calculate using speed condition.

Comment: how do you calculate the distance 55 km based on your previous speed logs?

Comment: i am just using it to find if there's a correlation